# In R, is there a way to split one categorical variable into three based on a condition?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm trying to create a random forest machine learning algorithm on the performance of some retail items. I'm using R Studio for this. In my dataset, I have a mix of both numeric and categorical variables. My issue is that one of my categorical variables, "Supplier", has more than 53 factors (166 to be exact), so the randomForest package I"m using won't let me use it. The dataset looks like this:

**Month Year Supplier ItemName UnitsSoldTY UnitsSoldLY Price Category NumberStores**

I believe that the "Supplier" variable will be very important to the model. To get around the limit of 53 factors to a categorical variable, I'd like to split the "Supplier" column up into three columns. However, I'd like the first column to contain the top 33% of suppliers by 'UnitsSold' across the entire dataset. The second column would be the middle 33% of suppliers by 'UnitsSold', and the third column would be the bottom 33% of suppliers by 'UnitsSold'. So the finished product, for the three columns, would look something like this:

**TopSupplier   MidSupplier   LowSupplier Month Year ItemName ...**
SupplierA    Other         Other
Other         SupplierB    Other
Other         Other         SupplierC

Any tips or suggestions on how to make this happen?

I've tried an ifelse statement, but can't seem to figure out how to rank suppliers across the entire dataset and then pull that into this as a factor for which supplier goes to which column.

I would like the final result to mimic the second table I included above. The 'Supplier' variable would be broken out across three columns. The first column would only contain suppliers that make up the top 33% of 'UnitsSold' from the entire dataset. The second column would be the middle 33%, and the third column would make be the bottom 33%.

Comment: Instead of doing that, you could think of grouping values in `Supplier` so that the factors come down. Too high number of factors do not help much in a RandomForest or any decisiontree based model

Comment: Is there an easy way to group them, maybe by percentile? Any sort of function in any package that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to add three new columns? Why don’t you create one column with three values (1 for the top-suppliers, 2 for the mid-suppliers and 3 for the low-suppliers)? Have you considered frequency or target encoding?